# nameError in django model.py

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

i made a class named Airport in models.py, but when i am feeding data through shell its giving me nameError: name 'Airport' is not defined

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Airport(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.city} ({self.code})"

class Flight(models.Model):
    origin = models.ForeignKey(Airport, on_delete =models.CASCADE, related_name="departures")
    destination = models.ForeignKey(Airport, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="arrivals")
    duration = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id}: {self.origin} to {self.destination}"
```

Comment: How are you feeding data through the shell? Can you share the script?

Comment: Did you run `makemigrations` and `migrate`?

Comment: yeah i have done all of that

Comment: first i did makemigrations then migrate then wrote jfk = Airport(code="JFK", city="New York") and when i hit the enter it started showing me nameError

Comment: Did you import `Airport` from your app.models & also check if your app is added in `INSTALLED_APPS` in `your_project_name/settings.py`. And I hope for shell you are using `python manage.py shell` not `ipython`

Comment: the app name is "Flight" not "Airport". "Airport" is a class which is created in models.py and the app name is added in INSTALLED_APPS. and yeah i'm using python manage.py shell